# Incorrect Instance Type for derived provided type in F# Erased Type Provider

Tags: entity-framework, f#, type-providers

I am working on a couple F# Type Providers to replace some half-baked code generation, and I'm having some issues with provided types that extend a base type.  For instance, one of the providers is an Entity Framework provider where the metadata for the database schema is coming from an outside source, and I'm providing a type that uses DbContext as its base type.  That type has properties to access the various DbSet<'table> members, but when I try to access those properties, I get the error `Incorrect instance type.  Parameter name: obj`.

I believe this is due to the 'this' parameter (the first argument in the GetterCode and SetterCode of the provided property) actually being of type DbContext, and not my derived provided type.  This would make sense, as my ProvidedConstructor for the context type is calling the DbContext constructor, but I'm not sure what else it could do.  I can only surmise that I'm misunderstanding something about how the types are created.  My code for the type definiton, constructor, and property are as follows.  Please let me know if I'm doing something incorrectly.

```
let contextType = ProvidedTypeDefinition("MyContext", Some typeof<DbContext>)
let dbContextCtor = typeof<DbContext>.GetConstructor([|typeof<string>|])

let defaultCtor = // Use static parameter 'sqlConnection'
    ProvidedConstructor(List.Empty, 
        BaseConstructorCall = (fun args -> dbContextCtor, args), 
        InvokeCode = fun args -> Expr.NewObject(dbContextCtor, [ <@@ sqlConnection @@> ]))
let stringCtor = 
    ProvidedConstructor([ProvidedParameter("sqlConnection", typeof<string>)], 
        BaseConstructorCall = (fun args -> dbContextCtor, args), 
        InvokeCode = fun args -> Expr.NewObject(dbContextCtor, [ args.[1] ]))

contextType.AddMember(defaultCtor)
contextType.AddMember(stringCtor)
```

...

```
// Add a DbSet field and property for each table to the context type
for providedType in providedTableTypes do
    let fieldType = typedefof<DbSet<_>>.MakeGenericType([|providedType|])
    let dbSetField = ProvidedField(sprintf "_%s" providedType.Name, fieldType)
    let dbSetProperty = 
        ProvidedProperty(providedType.Name, fieldType, 
            GetterCode = (fun args -> Expr.FieldGet(args.[0], dbSetField)),
            SetterCode = fun args -> Expr.FieldSet(args.[0], dbSetField, args.[1]))
    dbSetField.SetFieldAttributes(FieldAttributes.HasDefault)
    contextType.AddMember dbSetField
    contextType.AddMember dbSetProperty
```

The table types are generated and DbSet properties are added to the context type, but when I attempt to access one of the properties, I receive the `Incorrect instance type` error when the `GetterCode` expression is evaluated.

Comment: yeah, nevermind, let me get rid of that.

Comment: I don't think `ProvidedField`s make sense on an erased type (where would the field's storage exist?); also, you may need to use `ProvidedTypeBuilder.MakeGenericType(typedefof<DbSet>, providedType)` rather than `typedefof<DbSet>.MakeGenericType(providedType)`.

Comment: Do you think it would be prudent to switch to a Generated Type Provider?  I was a little tentative about going that route, since I don't have any experience with Generated Providers and there's not a lot of sample code available, but it seems like it is actually more in-line with my intended design.

Comment: I'd definitely stick to erased if their constraints don't conflict with your requirements - they are much simpler.  Without knowing more details about your scenario, it's hard for me to guess whether what you're trying to do is possible without resorting to a generated type provider.

Comment: Essentially, there is a metadata service that defines the logical schema for a large SQL database with thousands of tables.  The physical schema is different, and less developer-friendly than the logical schema, so I don't want to simply use Entity Framework against the physical schema.  Rather, I'm trying to use a Type Provider to offer the developers types that match the logical schema, but still use entity framework to query the physical schema in the background.

Comment: @AaronM.Eshbach did you ever find a solution to the errors you were receiving?  I am running into this exact same issue.